# Fitting the paired t-test with replicates and obtaining the explicit variance estimates: lme() vs. aov() in R

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, t-test, paired-data

### Summary of the question

I will show how to fit a certain model in R with `lme` and how to test the nullity of the parameter of interest $\delta$ with `aov`. The results are equivalent, up to the wrong number of degrees of freedom given by `lme` (and assuming `lme` does not return an almost null estimate of the between-group variance $\sigma^2_b$).

The `lme` fitting provides estimates of the variance components of the model. My question is how to find, if possible, these estimates from the results of `aov`.

### Data and model

The dataset is simulated by the function `SimData` below

```
library(data.table)
SimData <- function(I, J, delta, sigmab, sigmaw, rho){
  Mu <- setNames(c(0, delta), c("t1", "t2"))
  Sigma <- rbind(
    c(sigmab^2, rho*sigmab^2),
    c(rho*sigmab^2, sigmab^2)
  )
  ### simulation between-groups ###
  mu <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(I, Mu, Sigma)
  ### simulation within-groups ###
  y1 <- c(vapply(mu[,"t1"], function(x) rnorm(J, x, sigmaw), 
                 FUN.VALUE = numeric(J)))
  y2 <- c(vapply(mu[,"t2"], function(x) rnorm(J, x, sigmaw), 
                 FUN.VALUE = numeric(J)))
  ### constructs the dataset ####
  Timepoint <- gl(2L, I*J, labels=c("t1", "t2"))
  Group <- as.factor(paste0("grp", rep(gl(I,J), times=2L)))
  dat <- data.table(
    Timepoint = Timepoint,
    Group     = Group,
    y         = c(y1, y2), 
    key = c("Timepoint", "Group")
  )
  return(dat)
}
```

Below is a plot of a small simulated dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(105L)
DTsmall <- SimData(I=3L, J=4L, delta=0, sigmab=3, sigmaw=1, rho=0)
ggplot(DTsmall, aes(x=Timepoint, y=y, color=Group)) + geom_point(size=2)
```

[image]

Say that the observations are measurements taken on $I$ groups at two timepoints, 
and $J$ measurements are recorded for each group at each timepoint. 
We make the assumptions:

- the within-group variance is common to the $I$ groups at the two timepoints;
- the between-group variance is common to the two timepoints.

We use the indexes $i$, $j$ and $k$ to respectively denote the timepoint, the group and the observation.

We assume a correlation between the records of a same group taken at the two timepoints.

Mathematically, the theoretical pairs of means $(\mu_{1j}, \mu_{2j})$ of the groups are random effects following a bivariate normal distribution:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{1j} \\ \mu_{2j}
\end{pmatrix} 
\sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{1} \\ \mu_{2}
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2_{b} & \rho\sigma_{b}^2 \\
\rho\sigma_{b}^2  & \sigma^2_{b}
\end{pmatrix}
\right),
$$
centered around the theoretical pair of means $(\mu_1, \mu_2)$ at the two timepoints.
Then one assumes that for each timepoint $i$, the observations follow a normal distribution within each group $j$, with, as said before, a common within-variance $\sigma^2_{w}$:
$$
(y_{ijk} \mid \mu_{ij}) \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu_{ij}, \sigma^2_{w}).
$$

We set $\mu_1=0$ in the function `SimData`. We are interested in $\delta:=\mu_2-\mu_1$.

### Fitting the model with `lme`

Firstly, let's simulate a dataset with high values of $I$ and $J$ in order to check that the `lme` fitting correctly estimates the true parameters.

```
set.seed(31415L)
DTbig <- SimData(I=300, J=200, delta=1, sigmab=3, sigmaw=1, rho=0.5)
library(nlme)
fit_DTbig <- lme(y~Timepoint, data=DTbig,
                 random= list(Group= pdCompSymm(form= ~0+Timepoint)))
```

We find good estimates of $\sigma_b$, $\sigma_w$ and $\rho$:

```
VarCorr(fit_DTbig)
## Group = pdCompSymm(0 + Timepoint) 
##             Variance StdDev   Corr 
## Timepointt1 9.647973 3.106119      
## Timepointt2 9.647973 3.106119 0.522
## Residual    1.005556 1.002774
```

As well as good estimates of $\mu_1$ and $\delta$:

```
summary(fit_DTbig)$tTable
##                  Value Std.Error     DF   t-value      p-value
## (Intercept) 0.04328747 0.1793786 119699 0.2413191 8.093082e-01
## Timepointt2 0.99384798 0.1754768 119699 5.6637011 1.484807e-08
```

We will use the small dataset from now on:

```
fit <- lme(y~Timepoint, data=DTsmall,
           random= list(Group= pdCompSymm(form= ~0+Timepoint)))
sfit <- summary(fit)
( tTable <- sfit$tTable )
##                 Value Std.Error DF    t-value    p-value
## (Intercept) -1.350037 1.5919192 20 -0.8480561 0.40644218
## Timepointt2  2.559512 0.8364745 20  3.0598803 0.00618172
```

Recall that we are interested in the second row: the inference on $\delta$.

*Note:* The number of degrees of freedom in the above table is not correct; it should be $I-1$. Consequently the $p$-value is not correct.

### Testing $\delta$ with `aov`

```
AOV <- aov(y~ Timepoint + Error(Group/Timepoint), data=DTsmall)
sAOV <- summary(AOV)
( fTable <- sAOV$`Error: Group:Timepoint`[[1]] )
##           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
## Timepoint  1 39.307  39.307  9.3629 0.09226 .
## Residuals  2  8.396   4.198                  
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

This $F$-value is the square of the $t$-value given by `lme`:

```
fTable$`F value`[1]^0.5
## [1] 3.059879
tTable[2, "t-value"]
## [1] 3.05988
```

We can get the $t$-table with lsmeans:

```
lsm <- lsmeans::lsmeans(AOV, pairwise ~ Timepoint)
lsm$contrasts
##  contrast  estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
##  t1 - t2  -2.559512 0.836475  2   -3.06  0.0923
```

#### Side note: Testing $\delta$ with `t.test` on the group means

The design being balanced, we find the same results by applying the paired $t$-test to the group means:

```
DTmeans <- DTsmall[, .(means=mean(y)), by=.(Timepoint,Group)]
tt <- t.test(means ~ Timepoint, data=DTmeans, paired=TRUE)
tt$statistic
##         t 
## -3.059879
tt$p.value
## [1] 0.09226219
```

## Question

We can get the estimate of $\sigma^2_w$ from the `aov` results:

```
sAOV$`Error: Within`
##           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
## Residuals 18  13.02  0.7232
fit$sigma^2
## [1] 0.723177
```

The question is: how to get the estimates of $\sigma^2_b$ and $\rho$ ?

Here are the ones given by `lme`:

```
VarCorr(fit)
## Group = pdCompSymm(0 + Timepoint) 
##             Variance StdDev    Corr 
## Timepointt1 7.421826 2.7243029      
## Timepointt2 7.421826 2.7243029 0.883
## Residual    0.723177 0.8503982
```

Can we get these estimates from the tables below (or from the `AOV` object) ?

```
sAOV
## 
## Error: Group
##           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
## Residuals  2  113.2   56.62               
## 
## Error: Group:Timepoint
##           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
## Timepoint  1  39.31   39.31   9.363 0.0923 .
## Residuals  2   8.40    4.20                 
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Error: Within
##           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
## Residuals 18  13.02  0.7232
```

Comment: I'd like an explanation of this downvote ^^

Comment: Can you show the `varCorr` results from `fit` (the small dataset) so we can see what those estimates are?

Comment: @rvl They are given at the end, just before `sAOV`.

Comment: Duh - I'm blind I guess. It's striking that the estimated rho is so high given that the true value is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model fitted by `aov` is of the form
$$ y_{ijk} = \mu + \tau_k + G_i + \tau G_{ik} + E_{ijk} $$
which is a different parameterization of the model shown fitted using `lme`. The last three terms in the model are independent normal random variables, with variances $\sigma^2_G$, $\sigma^2_{\tau G}$, and $\sigma^2_E$ respectively.
Consulting a standard design text, one finds that
$$ E(MS(G)) = 8\sigma^2_G + 4\sigma^2_{\tau G} + \sigma_E^2 $$
$$ E(MS(\tau G)) = 4\sigma^2_{\tau G} + \sigma_E^2 $$
$$ E(MS(E)) = \sigma^2_E $$
Equating these expressions with the respective observed residual MSs for the three strata and solving, one obtains the method-of-moments estimates of these variances: $\hat\sigma^2_G = (56.62 - 4.20)/8 = 6.5525$, $\hat\sigma^2_{\tau G} = (4.20-.7232)/4 = 0.869$, $\hat\sigma^2_E=.7232$.

Under the model fitted by `lme`, the residual errors are the same $.7232$; but $\sigma^2_b = \sigma^2_G + \sigma^2_{\tau G}$ so that $\hat\sigma_b^2 = 6.553 + .869 = 7.42$. Meanwhile, $\rho$ is the intraclass correlation, $\hat\rho = 6.553/7.42=.882$.

Comment: Thank you infinitely! What is this book please?

Comment: *Remark:* `lmer(y ~ Timepoint + (1|Group/Timepoint))` gives these estimates, and the Kenward-Roger number of degrees of freedom is correct. On the other hand, `aov` does not really fit this model, because it possibly yields a negative estimate of $\rho$, as opposed to `lmer`.

Comment: One such book is Oehlert, *A First Course in Design of Experiments*, avail via Creative Commons, users.stat.umn.edu/~gary/book/fcdae.pdf. See Ch.12, especially 12.6. Yes, the $\rho$ estimate can go negative, in the same cases that it is estimated as zero by `lmer`; then you discard offending terms and get back on the same page.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Another question: are the numbers $8$ and $4$ universal or are they derived from $I$ and $J$ ?

Comment: I see, these are $2J$ and $J$.